# Python - Losing instances of variable when saving into list

Tags: python, list, instance

I have a function that appears to be saving the variable when I use `list.append`.  When I print each increment, the list changes.  When I print the full list of lists, every element is the same (the last instance of the variable list).  How can I force the master list to save the previous instances?

The base function just converts the list from base-10 to a new base (base-4 in my example)

```
list1 = ["v", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]

def combo(object_list, spots):
    pool = len(object_list)
    total = pool**spots
    permlist = list()
    wordlist = list()
    z = []
    for i in range(total):  
        print("top", wordlist) 
        wordlist.clear()
        z = base(i,pool,spots) 
        for q in z:  
            j=-1
            for a in object_list:
                j+=1
                if int(q) == int(j):
                    wordlist.append(a)
        permlist.append(wordlist)
    return permlist


def base(number, base, digits):
    remainder = []
    result = [0,0]
    while number >0:
        dividend = number // int(base)
        remainder.append(str(number % int(base)))
        number = dividend
        result = list(reversed(remainder))
    while len(result) < digits:
        result.insert(0,0)
    return result

print (combo(list1,4))
```

Comment: `permlist.append(wordlist.copy())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or,

```
wordlist = []
```

instead of

```
wordlist.clear()
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you!